# SQL query, by comparing values

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a form where you have to input the ammount to deposit (number), and a mysql table where it has a list of banks with the minimal ammount of deposit (like first row = `name`, second row = `minimal amount`).

The question is: **How can i query the database in order to show me the banks which are right for me according to minimal deposit value?** So example you want to deposit 50$, but not all banks allow you this as some of them have 100$ minimal deposit, so i want to show only those that have min.deposit below my amount.

Answer (score 1):

add a `WHERE` clause in your query as it will filter the records according to your needs,

```
SELECT *
FROM tableName
WHERE minimalAmount <= 50
```

Comment: And let's say that the amount is a variable from user input...ho it ill be (minimalAmount <= Useramount)

Comment: Damn this PHP, i perfectly did connect HTML dom with javascript, and now i don't have a clue how PHP treats dom elements. And i'm using php only coz i need to query a database.

Comment: Yes but the useramount is a input field...i need to catch it in PHP, like in javascript i did formname.select.value.....how do i do this kind of things in PHP?????????????

Comment: maybe you can visit this link about [PHP and MySQL](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/)